# d3 obtain arc.centroid (x, y) position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently working with d3 (just started learning it a few days ago). My project requires me to obtain the position of an arc.centroid(d). How would I do this? I have tried looking everywhere for a solution, but I cannot find one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You seem to be saying that you need to call `arc.centroid()` on something.

Comment: What I mean is that I need to get the data from arc.centroid() for each arc

Comment: So you need to call `arc.centroid` on each arc?

Comment: well yes, but also get the x coordinate position and y coordinate position of the center of the arc

Comment: That's what `arc.centroid` returns, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but how do you get the x coordinate only or the y coordinate only. I need to do something that is like (x value of center of arc)/2

Comment: `arc.centroid` returns a two-element array. The first element is the `x` coordinate, the second the `y` coordinate.

Comment: so how would you access those arrays?

Comment: You would save the return value of the function in a variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32066/discussion-between-alexyuiop-and-lars-kotthoff)